# Como criar um objeto dinamicamente a partir de uma interface?

Tags: typescript

Tenho a seguinte interface:

```
interface IInterface {
    Method1: (param1: any) => any;
    Method2: (param2: string[]) => any;
}
```

Eu gostaria que, a partir dela eu pudesse criar objetos dinamicamente que implementam e que todos os métodos fazem a mesma coisa, dependendo dos parâmetros passados.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
const keys = Reflect.ownKeys({} as IInterface);

let obj = {};
for (let key in keys) {
    obj[key] = (...params) => {
        console.log(`Chamou a função ${key}!`);
        return params.length > 0 ? params[0] : false;
    };
}

let obj2: IInterface = obj as IInterface; // Aqui eu teria a instancia de IInterface
```

Porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Nunca tinha visto esse objeto "`Reflect`". 

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo um pouco os conceitos. Interfaces são criadas para definir um contrato padrão que diferentes objetos devem obedecer. Uma interface não define *como* o método vai ser implementado. Parece que uma simples definição de classe resolveria seu problema... Talvez se você explicasse melhor na pergunta qual seria a utilização deste mecanismo que você quer, uma solução melhor poderia ser proposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Você não pode fazer isso.

---

TypeScript é um *superset* do JavaScript. Imagino que você já saiba disso, então não irei me prolongar muito nessa *histórinha* que todos já conhecem. A questão é que **o código TypeScript em si não é executado**. O que realmente acontece é que ele é transformado em JavaScript.  **Desse modo, o que realmente é executado é o código JavaScript.**

Assim, tendo em vista que as [`interfaces` do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) não são levadas ao código JavaScript (gerado através da "transpilação" do código TS), você não tem como gerar nenhum valor dinamicamente através delas. Você só pode usá-las (até o período em que escrevo essa resposta) para garantir a segurança de tipos (como inferência, definição de objetos, classes e afins) no seu código.

O que você deve fazer é criar o objeto *manualmente*:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
  gender: 'M' | 'F'
}

const luiz: Person = {
  name: 'Luiz Felipe',
  age: 16,
  gender: 'M'
}
```

Comment: Não sei se essa é uma boa justificativa, levando em conta que o Typescript poderia levar os metadados da interface junto ao código gerado caso identificasse que iria ser usado. De qualquer forma respondeu a minha pergunta no TL;DR. :)

Comment: É, mas até o momento, ele não leva as interfaces para o código JS gerado como output... Como você mesmo disse, ele "_poderia_" fazê-lo. Seria bem legal, alias!! :)